# Why does parenting an object in the hierarchy produce different results then parenting via script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[Parenting GIF (for visual)](https://ibb.co/iyKvaQ)

When parenting an object using the hierarchy you click and drag that object and place it into another game object.

When parenting an object using a script, it looks something like this

```
myObject.transform.SetParent(parentObject, false);
```

Now, if you watch the GIF you will see that the two different methods of parenting produce different results for the child objects transform values. The resulting position and scale are different for the child object depending on which approach to object parenting is used.

How do you get the same results produced when parenting in the hierarchy via click and drag, when parenting by script?

**EDIT:** Forgot to add that when watching the gif, you can see the click and drag parenting first and watch the transform values change. I then control Z to undo the change, click into the scene view, and execute a button press that sets the parent of the 'blue' game object to 'myObject'. Note, you will see the transform values don't change when parenting is done via the latter method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we check [Unity's API documentation for the SetParent()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html) method we can better understand how this method works. In my case I was using the method that used two parameters:

parent:
`The parent Transform to use`
worldPositionStays:
`When false the object keeps its local orientation rather than its global`

For my question, there are two simple solutions:

Set the worldPositionStays parameter to true so that the parent-relative position, scale and rotation are modified such that the child object keeps the same world space position, rotation and scale as before, or

Use the SetParent() method with only the parent parameter, effectively yields the exact same result as setting worldPositionStays to true.

Comment: It's a good thing to help others but note that this issue has been asked and solved so many times on this site.+1